# Is there a simple way to display a countdown to datetime in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I receive an object that is a DateTime, and I need to have a timer displayed on my component.

It is an expiration timer so on the timer hitting 0 I need to update the component.

I'm not sure how I should go about doing this, I cannot find any modules that do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setInterval directive like this: 
`setInterval(() => { this.loading = true; this.getSignals(); }, 60000);`

60000 its one minute.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **timer** from rxJS to set up your countdown. It takes a number in milliseconds in parameter, so you'll first have to substract your expiration date with the current time.
Then subscribe to the timer to call the code used to update your component.

```js
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

const remainingTime = expiration.getTime() - Date.now();

timer(remainingTime).subscribe(() => this.updateComponent);
```

Comment: There is no timer member in rxjs is there? Are you referring to timeinterval?

Comment: What is your version of rxjs?